# Inserting only new data from one table to another with different structures

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Inserting only new data from one table to another with different structures

Hi everyone,
I'm trying to insert in the table "userhr.nucleofam_ris" only the extra data present in "userhr.paghe_nucleo_fam".
But the error appears:

"Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =,! =, <, <=,>,> = Or when the subquery is used as an expression."

the problem is that I'm trying to enter a higher +1 kint for each more found record.

```
SELECT distinct
       (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY kint ASC) + 11000 from userhr.nucleofam_ris) as kint,
       hr01.kint as [kpadre]
      ,hr01.kint as [risorsa]
      ,hr05.parentela
      ,null as [gradoparentela]
      ,hr05.codfisc as [codfisc]
      ,hr05.cognome as [cognome]
      ,hr05.nome as [nome]
      ,concat(hr05.cognome,' ',hr05.nome) as [nominativo]
      ,hr05.sesso as [sesso] 
      ,hr05.datanasc as [nasc_data]
      ,null as [comune]
      ,null as [codice]
      ,null as [provincia]
      ,null as [stato]
      ,'NO' [disabile]
      ,null as [percdisab]
      ,'NO' AS [parto_plurimo]
      ,null as  [data_decesso]
      ,null as [data_presnascita_figlio]
      ,'NO' AS [acarico]
      ,'NO' AS [flessibilita]
      ,'NO' AS [sost_coniuge]
  FROM userhr.ris_umane hr01 INNER JOIN 
       userhr.wwrapp_ris hr03 ON (hr01.kint = hr03.kpar) INNER JOIN 
       userhr.rapp_lavoro_ris hr04 ON (hr03.karr = hr04.kint) INNER JOIN 
       userhr.paghe_nucleo_fam hr05 ON (hr04.kint = hr05.kpadre) 
where hr05.codfisc is not null 
      and hr05.cognome is not null 
      and hr05.nome is not null
      and NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                      FROM userhr.nucleofam_ris hr02 
                      WHERE hr02.codfisc = hr05.codfisc)
```

can you help me?

Comment: The error message is very clear: The inner select statement returns a table, which is not permitted. It can only return a single scalar value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have to try to insert in the target table userhr.nucleofam_ris a new record that has the max (kint) +1. can you help me?

Comment: If you want to return max(kint)+1 then select max(kint)+1 which will give you a single value, not row_number() which gives you a row per row in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

I think from your description that you want to create the next set of keys so that the rows you return can be inserted after the last row in your existing table.

This is an example that will do that, using two temporary table variables. It should point you in the right direction.

```
declare @t1 table(k int, txt1 varchar(10))
insert @t1 values (1,'firstrow'),(2,'second'),(3,'third')

declare @t2 table(txt2 varchar(10))
insert @t2 values ('a'),('b'),('c')

select row_number() over(order by txt2)
    +(select max(k) from @t1) NewKey, 
    txt2 
from @t2 t2
```

Result is:

```
NewKey  txt2
4       a
5       b
6       c
```